# create octree by bottom up approach in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, object, pyspark, octree

I have to create octree in parallel on Pyspark dataframe. and I have to use create octree with bottom up approach. i am not able to clearly understand bottom up approach. Can someone please write briefly direction? what I need to start. First I divided all points into 8 chunks.
Help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [spark3D](https://astrolabsoftware.github.io/spark3D/)? Information on Octree partitioning in Python is [here](https://astrolabsoftware.github.io/spark3D/docs/repartitioning/python/).